# How should I import Paper.js in Svelte?

Tags: npm, svelte, paperjs, rollupjs

I'm using the standard Svelte template with Rollup and have not been able to successfully import [Paper.js](http://paperjs.org/).

I installed paper via:

```
npm install paper
```

and I get this output trying to do `npm run dev` after importing Paper:

```
(!) Missing global variable name
Use output.globals to specify browser global variable names corresponding to external modules
acorn (guessing 'acorn')
```

Acorn is a dependency of the `paper-full.js` disto, and I'm looking to map

```
import { paper } from "paper";
```

to `paper-core.js` (although it would be very cool to get PaperScript from the full distro working in Svelte, but that's likely a whole other can of worms).

I'm wondering what kind of Rollup config I would need to add to resolve this.

[Here's the repo I'm working on](https://github.com/tonyketcham/paper-svelte) if you'd like some more context or a quick way to jump to exactly where I'm at.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE: Got it working! I had forgotten to install acorn as a dependency. I also switched to installing them both as devDependencies since rollup bundles everything. -- solution credit to Antony in the Svelte Discord